# constexpr static метод

Tags: c++, visual-c++, constexpr

Изучаю C++, полез в constexpr, но почти сразу наткнулся на странности.
У меня есть класс `Date`, который хранит дату, у него есть метод
`static bool isLeapYear(unsigned short)`,
к которому я попробовал добавить `constexpr`, таким образом:

*Объявление*

```
class Date{

    // ...

    constexpr static bool isLeapYear(unsigned short);

    // ...

};
```

*Определение*

```
constexpr bool Date::isLeapYear(ushort year)
{
    return year % 4 == 0;
}
```

*Попытка использования*

```
constexpr bool p = Date::isLeapYear(2000);
```

*Ругань компилятора*

```
1>c:\...\main.cpp(13): error C2131: выражение не определяется константой
1>c:\...\main.cpp(13): note: сбой был вызван неопределенной функцией или функцией, не объявленной как "constexpr"
1>c:\...\main.cpp(13): note: см. использование "Date::isLeapYear"
```

При этом аналогичное использование **точно такой же** функции *не члена класса* успешно компилируется.

Comment: И где же располагается ваше определение функции? Constexpr функции являются inline и должны подчиняться тем же требованиям.

Comment: И, кстати говоря, ваше определение неверное (если только вы не пишете для юлианского календаря aka старый стиль).  Правильно - `return (year%400==0)||((year%4==0)&&(year%100!=0));`